# Unable to locate package "csh"

Tags: apt, package-management, tcsh, csh

I tried installing `csh`, but it throws me the error:

```
unable to locate package csh
```

My Ubuntu version is 12.04.

Comment: how did you install it?

Answer (score 1):

`csh` and `tcsh` both are available in the `universe` repository in `precise` (Ubuntu 12.04).

You need to:

- [Enable the `universe` repository](https://askubuntu.com/q/148638)
- Update local package list for repositories:

  ```
  sudo apt-get update
  ```
- Install `csh`, `tcsh`:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install csh tcsh
  ```

Answer (score 0):

From [Ubuntu](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/csh), the package is Ubuntu `universe` repository.

See this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository) at AskUbuntu to enable the `universe` repository.

Then, type in the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install csh
```